# Convert <BR> tag to Char(10)

Tags: javascript

I want to convert `<br>` tags to `Char(10)` in javascript for later processing. However I don't understand how to convert the tag to the char code.

I have tried multiple things, below are two, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
var cleaned = str.split("<br>").join("\n");

var cleaned = str.split("<br>").join().fromCharCode(10);
```

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/x1t5bsoj/

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean `str.split("<br>").join(String.fromCharCode(10));`?

Comment: `var cleaned = str.split("<br>").join("\n");` Is probably working just fine; if you `console.log` the result, you'll see it does indeed have a newline. However, that newline isn't going to display as a newline in your HTML, since HTML ignores newlines. That's what `<br>`s are for.

Comment: it works, just change your `<div>` to `<pre>` so it doesn't ignore whitespace

Comment: You were right @Hamms ! Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You want a string replace. The below example uses a regular expression that does case insensitive global replacement.

```
data = data.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");
data = data.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
```

If you don't want it to do a case insensitive replace then remove the case-insensitive modifier "i" as seen below:

```
data = data.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
data = data.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
```